# Directly accessing the NSPopupButtonCell of an NSPopupButton (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos, nspopupbuttoncell, nspopupbutton

I know this is not normally recommended but I really need to access the NSPopupButtonCell of NSPopupButton.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[myPopup cell];
```

Kind of obvious, when you think about it. ;)

Really, tho'; `NSPopUpButton : NSButton : NSControl`; `NSControl` has `-[cell]`, so `NSPopUpButton` does too.

I guess what I'm trying to say, is; if you can't find a method that the object you are looking at *must* have, check its superclasses. (Or just use text completion in Xcode and a few lucky guesses. ;)